# Npm link is not Working in Angular7 Project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular7, npm-link

I have created an Angular7 Application and have to install another Angular Application as a widget in my Main Angular Application.

I used `npm-link` to link the widget Angular Application with my main Angular Application.

Steps for `npm link`

1. In cmd in the Main Project folder Ran command `npm link ../ol-core-widget`

The `ol-core widget` project has been linked to my Main Project and when I update `ol-core-widget` that file also updates in `node_modules/` in the main project.
But when my main project tries to access files from `ol-core-widget`, it fails.

2. After that I ran `npm install`, but it removed all the links.

If I make any changes in my widget application, then I have to create a `.tgz` file for that project, and then install it in my main angular app.

Version Info:

- npm `6.4.1`
- node `10.13.0`
- Angular Cli `7.0.3`